# SwiftUI - Adding a keyboard toolbar button for only one TextField adds it for all TextFields

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-toolbar

### Background

I have two `TextField`s, one of which has a keyboard type of `.decimalPad`.

Given that there is no 'Done' button when using a decimal pad keyboard to close it, rather like the return key of the standard keyboard, I would like to add a 'Done' button within a toolbar above they keypad *only for the decimal keyboard* in SwiftUI.

### Problem

Adding a `.toolbar` *to any `TextField`* for some reason adds it to all of the `TextField`s instead! I have tried conditional modifiers, using focussed states and checking for the `Field` value (but for some reason it is not set when checking, maybe an ordering thing?) and it still adds the toolbar above the keyboard for both `TextField`s.

How can I only have a `.toolbar` for my single `TextField` that accepts digits, and not for the other `TextField` that accepts a string?

### Code

*Please note that I've tried to make a minimal example that you can just copy and paste into Xcode and run it for yourself. With Xcode 13.2 there are some issues with displaying a keyboard for `TextField`s for me, especially within a sheet, so maybe simulator is required to run it properly and bring up the keyboard with cmd+K.*

```
import SwiftUI

struct TestKeyboard: View {
    @State var str: String = ""
    @State var num: Float = 1.2

    @FocusState private var focusedField: Field?
    private enum Field: Int, CaseIterable {
        case amount
        case str
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Spacer()
            
            // I'm not adding .toolbar here...
            TextField("A text field here", text: $str)
                .focused($focusedField, equals: .str)

            // I'm only adding .toolbar here, but it still shows for the one above..
            TextField("", value: $num, formatter: FloatNumberFormatter())
                .keyboardType(.decimalPad)
                .focused($focusedField, equals: .amount)
                .toolbar {
                    ToolbarItem(placement: .keyboard) {
                        Button("Done") {
                            focusedField = nil
                        }
                    }
                }

            Spacer()
        }
    }
}

class FloatNumberFormatter: NumberFormatter {
    override init() {
        super.init()
        
        self.numberStyle = .currency        
        self.currencySymbol = "€"
        self.minimumFractionDigits = 2
        self.maximumFractionDigits = 2
        self.locale = Locale.current
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
    }
}

// So you can preview it quickly
struct TestKeyboard_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        TestKeyboard()
    }
}
```

Comment: As long as they are in the same view, both keyboards will have the done button. That is the way `toolbar` works. There are some pre-iOS 15 tutorials on how to add a button to a keyboard that should do what you want. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59894649/7129318).

Comment: @Yrb I *almost* have your suggestion working with a float, but using `NumberFormatter` doesn't work, and the view is taking up the rest of the screen. It's not behaving like I would expect. Is there something else I'm missing? [Code](https://pastebin.com/EWWZ2wE6). PS - thanks for your response, again!

Comment: I was able to use `numberFormatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: value))!`. But then you can remove the symbol. I feel like this is quite a hack compared with what I was trying to do with the iOS 15 specific stuff with SwiftUI..

Comment: for me toolbar appears across the other presented views, but coming `grayed out` as disabled. also not releasing focus :(

Answer (score 8):

Try to make toolbar content conditional and move toolbar outside, like below. (No possibility to test now - just idea)

Note: test on real device

```
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        Spacer()
        
        TextField("A text field here", text: $str)
            .focused($focusedField, equals: .str)

        TextField("", value: $num, formatter: FloatNumberFormatter())
            .focused($focusedField, equals: .amount)
            .keyboardType(.decimalPad)

        Spacer()
    }
    .toolbar {          // << here !!
        ToolbarItem(placement: .keyboard) {
            if field == .amount {             // << here !!
               Button("Done") {
                  focusedField = nil
               }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. It looks like the conditional is evaluated once, and never again. In my testing only the initial value of `field` would make toolbar either appear or not appear.

Comment: Also it doesn't work without adding NavigationView :|

Answer (score 5):

I tried it a lot but I ended up in the below one.

```
    .focused($focusedField, equals: .zip)
                .toolbar{
                    ToolbarItem(placement: .keyboard) {
                        switch focusedField{
                        case .zip:
                            HStack{
                                Spacer()
                                Button("Done"){
                                    focusedField = nil
                                }
                            }
                        default:
                                Text("")
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Comment: It worked. This should be marked as the right answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

This is my solution:

```
func textFieldSection(title: String,
                      text: Binding<String>,
                      keyboardType: UIKeyboardType,
                      focused: FocusState<Bool>.Binding,
                      required: Bool) -> some View {
    TextField(
        vm.placeholderText(isRequired: required),
        text: text
    )
    .focused(focused)
    .toolbar {
        ToolbarItemGroup(placement: .keyboard) {
            if focused.wrappedValue {
                Spacer()
                Button {
                    focused.wrappedValue = false
                } label: {
                    Text("Done")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For my project I have five `TextField` views on one View, so I created this method in the View's extension.

I pass the unique `FocusState<Bool>.Binding` value and use it in the ToolbarItemGroup closure to determine if we should display the content (Spacer, Button). If the particular TextField is `focused`, we display the toolbar content (all other unfocused TextFields won't).

Comment: The only answer that works correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Using [introspect](https://github.com/siteline/SwiftUI-Introspect) you can do something like this in any part in your View:

```
.introspectTextField { textField in
                    textField.inputAccessoryView = UIView.getKeyboardToolbar {
                        textField.resignFirstResponder()
                    }
            }
```

and for the `getKeyboardToolbar`:

```
extension UIView {

static func getKeyboardToolbar( _ callback: @escaping (()->()) ) -> UIToolbar {
        let toolBar = UIToolbar(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width, height: 44))
        let doneButton = CustomBarButtonItem(title: "Done".localized, style: .done) { _ in
            callback()
        }
        
        let space = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
        toolBar.items = [space, doneButton]
        
        return toolBar
    }

}
```

and for the `CustomBarButtonItem` this is a bar button item that takes a closure

```
import UIKit

class CustomBarButtonItem: UIBarButtonItem {
    typealias ActionHandler = (UIBarButtonItem) -> Void

    private var actionHandler: ActionHandler?

    convenience init(image: UIImage?, style: UIBarButtonItem.Style, actionHandler: ActionHandler?) {
        self.init(image: image, style: style, target: nil, action: #selector(barButtonItemPressed(sender:)))
        target = self
        self.actionHandler = actionHandler
    }

    convenience init(title: String?, style: UIBarButtonItem.Style, actionHandler: ActionHandler?) {
        self.init(title: title, style: style, target: nil, action: #selector(barButtonItemPressed(sender:)))
        target = self
        self.actionHandler = actionHandler
    }

    convenience init(barButtonSystemItem systemItem: UIBarButtonItem.SystemItem, actionHandler: ActionHandler?) {
        self.init(barButtonSystemItem: systemItem, target: nil, action: #selector(barButtonItemPressed(sender:)))
        target = self
        self.actionHandler = actionHandler
    }

    @objc func barButtonItemPressed(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        actionHandler?(sender)
    }
}
```

Comment: somehow I don't like this library but it is the only answer which worked for me. thanks

Answer (score 1):

**Number Pad return solution in SwiftUI,**
**Tool bar button over keyboard,**
**Focused Field**

```
struct NumberOfBagsView:View{
   @FocusState var isInputActive: Bool
   @State var phoneNumber:String = ""
   TextField("Place holder",
                  text: $phoneNumber,
                  onEditingChanged: { _ in
                
            //do actions while writing something in text field like text limit
            
        })
        .keyboardType(.numberPad)
        .focused($isInputActive)
        .toolbar {
            ToolbarItem(placement: .keyboard) {

                Button("Done") {
                    print("done clicked")
                    isInputActive = false
                }
                
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I've found wrapping each `TextField` in its own `NavigationView` gives each its own context and thus a unique toolbar. It feels not right and I've seen constraint warnings in the console. Use something like this:

```
   var body: some View {
    VStack {
        Spacer()
        
        // I'm not adding .toolbar here...
        NavigationView {
          TextField("A text field here", text: $str)
            .focused($focusedField, equals: .str)
        }
        // I'm only adding .toolbar here, but it still shows for the one above..
        NavigationView {
          TextField("", value: $num, formatter: FloatNumberFormatter())
            .keyboardType(.decimalPad)
            .focused($focusedField, equals: .amount)
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .keyboard) {
                    Button("Done") {
                        focusedField = nil
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        Spacer()
    }
}
```

Comment: that didn't work for me. guess cuz i've got NavigationView's in parent views as well

Answer (score -2):

There is work. But the other TextField will still display toolbar.

--- update ---
Hi, I updated the code to use ViewModifier to make the code easier to use and this time the code does compile and run >_<

```
struct ToolbarItemWithShow<Toolbar>: ViewModifier where Toolbar: View {
    var show: Bool
    let toolbar: Toolbar
    let placement: ToolbarItemPlacement
    
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content.toolbar {
            ToolbarItemGroup(placement: placement) {
                ZStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    if show {
                        HStack { toolbar }
                            .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width - 12)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

extension View {
    func keyboardToolbar<ToolBar>(_ show: Bool, @ViewBuilder toolbar: () -> ToolBar) -> some View where ToolBar: View {
        modifier(ToolbarItemWithShow(show: show, toolbar: toolbar(), placement: .keyboard))
    }
}


struct ContentView: View {
    private enum Field: Hashable {
        case name
        case age
        case gender
    }
    
    @State var name = "Ye"
    @State var age = "14"
    @State var gender = "man"
    
    @FocusState private var focused: Field?

    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("Name", text: $name)
                .focused($focused, equals: .name)
                .keyboardToolbar(focused == .name) {
                    Text("Input Name")
                }
            
            TextField("Age", text: $age)
                .focused($focused, equals: .age)
                .keyboardToolbar(focused == .age) {
                    Text("Input Age")
                }

            TextField("Gender", text: $gender)
                .focused($focused, equals: .gender)
                .keyboardToolbar(focused == .gender) {
                    Text("Input Sex")
                }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

--- old ---

```
struct TextFieldWithToolBar<Label, Toolbar>: View where Label: View, Toolbar: View {
    @Binding public var text: String
    public let toolbar: Toolbar?

    @FocusState private var focus: Bool

    var body: some View {
        TextField(text: $text, label: { label })
            .focused($focus)
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItemGroup(placement: .keyboard) {
                    ZStack(alignment: .leading) {
                        if focus {
                            HStack {
                                toolbar
                                Spacer()
                                Button("Done") {
                                    focus = false
                                }
                            }
                            .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width - 12)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
    }
}

TextFieldWithToolBar("Name", text: $name)
TextFieldWithToolBar("Name", text: $name){
    Text("Only Brand")
}
TextField("Name", "Set The Name", text: $name)
```

[with Done](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uN9V7t.png) [with Toolbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X41aht.png) [without](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bCXlYt.png)

Comment: have you forgot to add label variable? try to compile you code please. also i'm not sure that there's such a constructor for `TextField` (SwiftUI 3). for me it's not working

Comment: Sorry I was too careless, I updated the code. Make sure the code works this time.